# Lwjgl MouseDwheel not getting 0

Tags: java, opengl, input, mouse, lwjgl

In my Opengl Engine i have the following code to manage the mouse input stuff:

```
protected static void Mouse(){
        mousex = Mouse.getX();
        mousey = Mouse.getY();
        mouseDx = Mouse.getDX();
        mouseDy = Mouse.getDY();
        mouseWheelState = Mouse.getEventDWheel() / 120;
        while(Mouse.next()){
            int eventButton = Mouse.getEventButton();
            if(Mouse.getEventButtonState()){
                for(MouseListener listener : MouseManager.listener){
                    listener.mousePressed(AGLMouseButton.valueOf(Mouse.getButtonName(Mouse.getEventButton())));
                }
            }
            else if(eventButton > -1){
                for(MouseListener listener : MouseManager.listener)
                listener.mouseReleased(AGLMouseButton.valueOf(Mouse.getButtonName(Mouse.getEventButton())));
            }
        }
    }
```

my problem is that mouseWheelState never gets zero. if i rotate the weel up, mouseWheelState is 1 until i rotate it down.

How i could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mouse.getEventDWheel()` gets the delta for the mouse wheel movement. Even if you don't touch the wheel it will report small changes.

An easy way to solve this is to use a 'deadband', a region where the changes are not accepted.

```
mouseWheelState = Mouse.getEventDWheel();

if(Math.abs(mouseWheelState)<deadbandWidth)
{
  mouseWheelState = 0;
}
mouseWheelState /= 120;
```